# Piecewise and ProbabilityDistribution malfunction when used together

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, piecewise

Yesterday I opened [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140812/how-i-can-define-a-discrete-probability-distribution-with-parameters), what had a happy end after all.

But when I tried to model more complex discrete random variables using `Piecewise` instead of `If` I discovered that it doesnt work at all!! Example:

1.This code works perfectly:

```
(*Our pseudo-generating function*)
g[x_, m_, c_, bigD_, t_, d_] := 
 ((c/bigD)/x + (bigD - t - c)/bigD + (t - d) x/bigD + (d/bigD) x^2)^m

(*Probability mass function of k*)
f[k_, m_, c_, bigD_, t_, d_] := 
 If[k == 0, 
  Sum[Coefficient[g[x, m, c, bigD, t, d], x, i], {i, -m, 0}], 
  Coefficient[g[x, m, c, bigD, t, d], x, k]]

(*We make a probability distribution*)
dist[m_, bigD_: 6, t_: 2, d_: 0, c_: 0] := 
  ProbabilityDistribution[f[k, m, c, bigD, t, d], {k, 0, 2 m, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> {bigD \[Element] Integers, 0 <= d < bigD, 
     0 <= c < bigD, 1 <= t < bigD, m \[Element] Integers && m > 0}];

(* Testing some statistics*)
{Mean[#], StandardDeviation[#], 
   Table[Evaluate@CDF[#, k], {k, 0, 5}]} &@dist[5]
```

2.But this alternative code (based in the function `g` above described) doesnt work from `dist2`:

```
(*Alternative probability mass function of k*)
h[k_, m_, c_, bigD_, t_, d_] := Piecewise[
  {
   {Sum[Coefficient[g[x, m, c, bigD, t, d], x, i], {i, -m, 0}], k == 0},
   {Coefficient[g[x, m, c, bigD, t, d], x, k], k != 0}
  }]

(*Probability distribution based on h (this is where the code seems fail)*)
dist2[m_, bigD_: 6, t_: 2, d_: 0, c_: 0] := 
  ProbabilityDistribution[h[k, m, c, bigD, t, d], {k, 0, 2 m, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> {bigD \[Element] Integers, 0 <= d < bigD, 
     0 <= c < bigD, 1 <= t < bigD, m \[Element] Integers && m > 0}];

(* The test reveal that dist2 is not working as expected *)
Table[Evaluate@PDF[dist2[5], k], {k, 0, 5}]
```

I discovered that the function `h` evaluates correctly, and give the same results than `f`, but when I used together with `ProbabilityDistribution` to define `dist2` it seems that the code dont work correctly.

There is a way to fix this? And in general, there is a way to use piecewise functions (with more than two pieces) together with `ProbabilityDistribution`? Thank you in advance.

---

UPDATE: the `Boole` function, as someone commented, is not working either but I found an (ugly) solution by the moment that is based in nesting `If` statements to define a piecewise function of more than two pieces inside of `ProbabilityDistribution`.

Comment: I had similar problems recently (cf. [(129690)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129690/764)). One is well advised to avoid using `Piecewise` and turn to `Boole` instead.

Comment: @gwr sorry to say but `Boole` is not working either. I mean that `If`, `Piecewise` and `Boole` evaluates correctly but when you put inside of `ProbabilityDistribution` only the first one works.